# Event Listener fires on wrong target / function executes at the wrong time

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm having a problem with an event listener which is firing on the wrong object.

To see it, please click on one td with a number below 'Min'

Here's the full js code:

```js
var minedit = document.getElementsByClassName('min-edit');
     for (var m=0;m<minedit.length;m++){
        minedit[m].addEventListener('click', edit);
     }
    
    function edit(){
        this.removeEventListener('click', edit);
        var avalue = this.innerHTML;
    
        if (this.className.indexOf('input-open')>=0){
    
 
    }
    
    else {
        this.className += 'input-open';
        var content = '';
        content += '<div class="input-group editable-input"><input type="text" id="minedit'+this.parentNode.childNodes[1].id+'" value="'+parseFloat(avalue).toFixed(2)+'" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon editable-input" id="savethis"><i class="ion-android-done" ></i></span><span class="input-group-addon editable-input"><i class="ion-android-close" id="close"></i></span></span></div>';
        this.innerHTML = content;
    
     
        var valuenow = document.getElementById('minedit'+this.parentNode.childNodes[1].id).value;
        var id = document.getElementById('minedit'+this.parentNode.childNodes[1].id).id;
    
        var save = document.getElementById('savethis');
        save.addEventListener('click', savethis(valuenow, id));
    
    
    }
    function savethis(v,id) {
    
        console.log(id.replace('minedit','')+'Button clicked: '+v);
    }
    
    }
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e207wmmo/)

**What is happening:**

With this lines:

```
 var content = '';
 content += '<div class="input-group editable-input">
             <input type="text" id="minedit'+this.parentNode.childNodes[1].id+'" value="'+parseFloat(avalue).toFixed(2)+'" class="form-control">
             <span class="input-group-addon editable-input" id="savethis"><i class="ion-android-done" ></i></span>
             <span class="input-group-addon editable-input"><i class="ion-android-close" id="close"></i></span></span></div>';
 this.innerHTML = content;
```

I'm creating an input field and two spans, one of them with the id "savethis". Now I add the `eventlistener` on `savethis`:

```
 var valuenow = document.getElementById('minedit'+this.parentNode.childNodes[1].id).value;
 var id = document.getElementById('minedit'+this.parentNode.childNodes[1].id).id;

 var save = document.getElementById('savethis');
save.addEventListener('click', savethis(valuenow, id));
```

But the function `savethis` is called in the moment the innerHTML changes to the input field. You can see this in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e207wmmo/) when clicking on one of the 'Min' TDs.

Can someone help me with this? Why is the function called on click on a row and not on click on the span?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I can't see how it is duplicated, the suggested link is about onLoad, this question about action not working for specific target!

Comment: @Al-Mothafar The titles are different but the problem is the same. _executes at the wrong time_ here is _fires on page load_ (which is also the wrong time) in the dupe. I actually was looking for a dupe for another question and found these two and noticed that they were the same so decided to close the least famous one (this one).

Comment: @Al-Mothafar If you look closely you'll see that in both questions OP is executing the function while adding the event listener: `savethis(valuenow, id)` here, `alert("clicktrack")` in dupe

Comment: Yeah, it's a dupe. How did you guys find this 3 year old question??? @ibrahimmahrir

Comment: @baao Goooooogle. They must have enhanced their search algorithms over the course of these passed 3 years.

Comment: Ah okay. @ibrahimmahrir . I would have deleted the question a while ago, but it's a dupe target to other questions, too...

Comment: OK I got it, actually Already experienced with JS, it is just as Ibrahim said he found that duplicate regarding solution :)

Comment: @baao No no don't delete it. The different titles may help people get to that dupe target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the addEventListener you are calling the savethis function instead of passing it in

Change

```
save.addEventListener('click', savethis(valuenow, id));
```

to

```
save.addEventListener('click', savethis);
```

And find another method to use valueNow and id in the savethis function.

This explains how to pass parameters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener